# What are these Chinese character stamps?

Tags: translation, mandarin, usage, characters

I found these stamps in an old book, what are they I can hardly make them out? And what do they mean.

[image]
[image]

Comment: 烟台(山东) · 长老传道会 · 郭显德 | It seems to be sent from Hunter Corbett from Yantai, Shandong as part of the Presbyterian Church.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stamp in the first picture says

> 郭顯德

It is a person's name, and if you prefer simplified Chinese, it would be

> 郭显德

The stamp in the second picture says

> 烟台 · 長老傳道會

The first two characters is the name of a city in Shandong province, while the rest is the name of a club.

Comment: these characters are in traditional chinese.

Answer (score 1):

烟台 · 長老傳道會 (second image) is the Presbyterian Church of Yantai, Shandong.